# Переполнение буфера стека. Ошибка "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)"

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

В общем проблема такова, что переполняется стек именно при вызове функции из другого файла
Код программы и остальное по данное ссылке: [Как выводить значение в функции в Label](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093477/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-label)

Comment: В общем, правильная практика публиковать минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему. Вопрос, на который вы ссылаетесь - принят вами как правильный.

Comment: Я не отрицаю того что мой код не правильный. Просто я хочу чтобы он заработал и разобраться почему не работал

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.